# Rehashing and resizing a chaining hash table with one struct

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I created a simple chaining hash table with a rehash/resize function but it does not seem to work. I´m not sure where is the problem. 
I would like to rehash when there are more than 5 elements stored at one key.
I know that debugger is my friend, I  tried to find the problem using debugger but I was not sucessfull. I know that probably this is not the best hash table ever made but this is the first time I am doing it.
Thanks for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10
#define CAPACITY 5
#define FACTOR 0.7       // not using currently

typedef struct hast_table_item
{
    int data;
    int key;
    struct hast_table_item *next_data;
}HASH_TABLE_ITEM;

int hash_function(int value)
{
    return value % MAX;
}

void display_hash_table(HASH_TABLE_ITEM **hash_table);

void rehash(HASH_TABLE_ITEM **old_hash_table) {
    int current_capacity = MAX;
    int old_capacity = current_capacity;
    int new_capacity = old_capacity*2;
    HASH_TABLE_ITEM *new_hash_table[new_capacity];
    int i_my_hash;

    /* Clear the table */
    for (i_my_hash=0; i_my_hash<new_capacity; i_my_hash++) {                         
        new_hash_table[i_my_hash] = NULL;
    }

    /* Do Rehash */
    for (i_my_hash=0; i_my_hash<old_capacity; i_my_hash++) {
        if (old_hash_table[i_my_hash]->key != NULL) {                      // Guess there is problem in this if statement
          insert_hti(new_hash_table, old_hash_table[i_my_hash]->data);
        }
    }
    display_hash_table(new_hash_table);
}

void check_capacity(HASH_TABLE_ITEM **hash_table, HASH_TABLE_ITEM *new_item) 
{
    int count = 0;
    HASH_TABLE_ITEM *current = new_item;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        if (hash_table[i] != NULL) {
            while (current != NULL) {
                count++;
                current = current->next_data;
                if (count == 5) {
                        printf("--- REHASHING ---\n");
                        rehash(hash_table);
                        // count = 0;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        } 
    }
    printf("Key %d has %d elements.\n",new_item->key, count);
}

void insert_hti(HASH_TABLE_ITEM **hash_table, int value)
{
    HASH_TABLE_ITEM *new_item = NULL;
    new_item = (HASH_TABLE_ITEM*)malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE_ITEM));

    new_item->data = value;
    new_item->key = hash_function(value);
    new_item->next_data = NULL;

    if (hash_table[new_item->key] == NULL) {
        hash_table[new_item->key] = new_item;
        check_capacity(hash_table,new_item);
    }
    else {
        new_item->next_data = hash_table[new_item->key];
        hash_table[new_item->key] = new_item;
        check_capacity(hash_table,new_item);
    }

}

void display_hash_table(HASH_TABLE_ITEM **hash_table) 
{
    HASH_TABLE_ITEM *current = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        if (hash_table[i] != NULL) {
            current = hash_table[i];
            printf("Table Key (%d) -->   ", i);

            while (current != NULL) {
                printf("   | Data: %d |", current->data);
                current = current->next_data;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    /* Declare My Hash */
    int insert_value_my_hash = 0;
    int i_my_hash;
    HASH_TABLE_ITEM* hash_table[MAX];

    /* Clear the table */
    for (i_my_hash=0; i_my_hash<MAX; i_my_hash++) {                         
        hash_table[i_my_hash] = NULL;
    }

    /* Insert into My Hash */
    while (scanf("%d", &insert_value_my_hash) == 1) {       
        insert_hti(hash_table, insert_value_my_hash);
        printf("Vložila som element %d do mojej Hash tabuľky.\n", insert_value_my_hash);
    }
    display_hash_table(hash_table);    
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't work" means? Produces the wrong value? Crashes? Have you tried compiling it with compiler warnings turned on?

Answer (score 0):

You're using local variable arrays for your hash tables (both the original and the rehashed one), but these need to be allocated and the pointers passed around.

Currently, when you rehash, you build the new table in the local `new_hash_table` array.  You fill that, then throw it away (leaking all the memory allocated for the nodes) at the end of the function.

Your hash function assumes the fixed size original array, and when you do a lot of extra work during rehashing that is unnecessary and just slows the performance.